# Specific image layout

Tags: graphics, positioning

I can combine graphics with the following:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\begin{center}$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\includegraphics{Figures/fig1.pdf}\\
\includegraphics{Figures/fig2.pdf}\\
\includegraphics{Figures/fig3.pdf}
\end{array}$
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

This combines the graphics specified into one figure where one graphic is placed under the other (which extend over both columns in the document). However, what I am trying to do is to have the first graphic to cover most of the page, and then have the second and third graphic on the same row but in different columns beneath it.

So, say if I had a matrix with 2 rows and 2 columns then the first graphic would be in the first row but extending over both columns and the second and third graphic would be in the second row, second and third column respectively. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you using a `twocolumn` document, or just the standard layout? What document class are you using?

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need an array for the images.

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics{Figures/fig1.pdf}

\includegraphics{Figures/fig2.pdf} \includegraphics{Figures/fig3.pdf}
\end{figure*}
```

Otherwise use `\multicolumn{2}[c}{\includegraphics{...}}`

Comment: This code just inserts the graphics underneath one another. I probably wasn't clear before so I'll re-phrase what Im trying to do. I'm trying to have the first graphic inserted as shown above, then have the second and third graphic as being on the same line underneath the first graphic, where the second and third graphic are preferably half the width of the first.

Comment: If the graphics come out beneath each other, the second and third are (together) too wide, that is, wider than `\linewidth`. The width of the graphic is controlled by the `width` option of `\includegraphics`, using an array won't change this.

Answer (score 4):

These type of layouts are difficult to achieve unless the dimensions of the images are known. In general you can enclose them in minipages and this will also allow captions to be included properly (Testing on demo can give you very different results). Enclosing them in minipages is necessary if you are going to have different captions for each image. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./graphics/agnewesclinic}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./graphics/mrswilliam}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./graphics/celloplayer}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{My figures}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more complicated example can be found at [dragnew](https://github.com/yannisl/MWE/tree/master/dragnew). With slightly more code, the caption of the first image was typeset as three column and also there was an additional side caption on one of the bottom images.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd have done this as a desperate attempt:

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Article Class (This is a LaTeX2e document)  ********************
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figures/fig1.pdf}
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.49\linewidth}
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figures/fig2.pdf}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\linewidth}
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figures/fig2.pdf}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{My figures}\label{fig:somelabel}
\end{figure*}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

It would have been better if the dimensions of your graphics were known along with a complete MWE for more details.

Comment: Why not just use `\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{...}` rather than putting the image inside a `minipage`?

Comment: @Werner, for sure it can be used and it is the simple and direct way. I was just experimenting for a change.

Comment: @HarishKumar Always better to enclose in minipages, especially if there are captions. Also having a top `minipage` or `vbox{}` is a good idea if you do not enclose within a figure environment.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, I was not aware of that. My instinct said that I use minibox. Sometimes instinct does good. Thanks for the information.